Options/strategies for career progression when support is missing
I am a manager "low" in the management hierarchy. I moved to a new area in my company a while back, hoping to get more opportunities for career progression.
Currently the situation is that

my team members are very happy with me
all the stakeholders have given good feedback about me
all our objectives are met and my manager has given me good feedback.

The problem I have is that I am not sure if my manager is actually interested in helping me progress. I don't think it is personal, I think her sole focus seems to be her own career progression.
What has been going on is that my manager has been giving me more and more delegations for work which take up more and more of my time, but what comes down to is its not really work that prepares me for next level progression.
Additionally she is not really open for any sort of input from me, either my input or even my team's input or concerns. Even for issues that my team members complain and that I can't solve as they're outside my reach, mentioning them to my manager for support or at least awareness on the team's feedback it ends up being brushed away. For things that are a blocker I try to find a solution on my own.
She also does not really ask my input on topics but just emphasises on announcing things and that's it. She has an authoritative approach and has also a communication style that reflects that too much.
In the past I have been multiple times in situations that I stayed doing my work diligently and hoping I will gain some momentum in my career but never really happened as somehow I am not as good as others in terms of moving my career forward fast.
In this situation, would you recommend that I give my manager feedback on my thoughts? Should I try to look for opportunities at another area and not mention anything? I am not sure what are options or strategies to follow when one feels stuck  in a specific area in terms of achieving their personal career objectives.

I feel examples would help. I don't know what "She also does not really ask my input on topics but just emphases on announcing things and that's it" means. Equally "its not really work that prepares me for next level progression" could be valid or not, depending on what the tasks are and what your organisation expects "next level" people to be able to do

@mattfreake:it means for example deciding to move a team member out of my team or adding someone without any input from me.

Firstly I would not bring up your opinions on your manager's behavior to them ie paragraphs 3-5. Nothing to be gained from that.Is your manager even the one responsible for deciding if you get promoted? Or is that up to their manager, or the board, etc? Once you figure that out, I would attempt to get some clear answers from your manager regarding progression. Schedule a meeting and ask them questions such as:

What do you see my career progress at this company looking like?
What milestones would you like to see me hit to consider promotion?
What do you see as a realistic timeline for me to get promoted?
I really like having X type of responsibilities. Can we work together to get me more tasks in that realm?

If the answers to these questions are to your liking, then stick around and see if your managers stays true to them. If they don't you can start looking for something else.

My manager is not responsible for deciding who gets promoted. It is expected of her to support her reports in career growth. In my case that would mean e.g. delegating work that would give me next level experience. She is delegating work to me but not really of that type. In regards about your point about nothing to be gained, I understand your point. I was thinking it might help her realise she has an impact on me, but I see it might also not work out properly

Gotcha. Well, I'd say these first three questions are still relevant because she should be able to run those up the ladder to whoever is responsible and find out the answers for you. The fourth question is definitely something you should bring up with her. Up to you how to do it, but I find unsolicited upwards criticism is risky. Framing it as something you want her to start doing as opposed to something you're upset that she isn't doing makes a big difference.

I mean, if she's delegating work to you it is work someone expects someone of her level to be handling...

@mxyzplk: the are other resources that can take over  the tasks actually. She seems to be taking more and more and delegating and I suspect is more for her own growth. So its not that specifically my/my team has to do it or even her specific area

@InBedded16: Just to be sure, what do you mean by fourth question? I am confused on the fourth

@smith well in my answer I listed four questions, so... the fourth. If you meant that you don't understand the point of the fourth question, its to ask her to give you more "work that prepares you for next level progression" as you put it.
